# Android, how to open camera with a timer in the middle of it, which counts from 10 to 0 , and can be interacted with, from withing the camera frame

Tags: android

This is my first question in stackoverflow.
What i am trying to achieve for starters ,is exactly the tittle.
Any answers that will solve the addressed issue, will help me very much in a project that i have in mind.
But for now, i just need to learn how to open the camera in an android application, with a widget in the middle of it, which the user can interact with.(For example, a counter that counts from 10 to 0, and if the user clicks on the camera, the counter will increase by 10)

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Do let us know what you have tried till now. It would be appreciatable if you could try some logic on your own and in case you get stuck, the community is there to answer. Good Luck